# Proving an inequality for an iterated sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence defined by the iteration
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+x_n}$$
With initial point $x_0 = 0$

I am asked to prove that
$$|x_{n+k}-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}|x_{n+1}-x_n|$$

I have already shown that
$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{4}|x_n-x_{n-1}|$$
which I'm guessing I need to use, but I'm struggling to figure out how.

Comment: Induction on $k$.  And you might as well replace the $2$ by a $4$.

Comment: I was thinking this, but it didn't seem to work out.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just doing the induction step wrong earlier.

Comment: Note that $x_1=\frac{1}{2}, x_2=\frac{2}{5}$ and $x_3=\frac{5}{12}$ . Hence $\frac{1}{2}|x_2-x_1|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{20}$ and $|x_3-x_1|=|\frac{5}{12}-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{12}.$ The statement is NOT TRUE for $n=1$ and $k=2$.